# React - Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm invoking a function like below and understand this is why im getting this error. Is there a way to not invoke the function but still pass the event property?

```
onMouseOver={(event) => { this.moveBall(event) }}
```

The reason for wanting to do this is so I can do a check in the function like so:

```
const element = event.target ? event.target : event;
```

As I want to re-use this function to pass an element through on load:

```
// Below line is in a constructor.
this.navItem = document.querySelector('.navigation__item');
// Being called after my render
this.moveBall(this.props.navItem);
```

Feels like this should be doable..

I've managed to fix this with the below code but I believe that there must be a better way to achieve this:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const activeState = document.querySelector('.navigation__item .active')
        this.moveBall(activeState)
    });
```

** Update ** 
Full component code
https://jsfiddle.net/fvn1pu5r/

Comment: 1.  Can you rewrite your JSX to `onMouseOver={this.moveBall}`? Will it still throw an error?
2. How did you declare your `this.moveBall` in you class? Did you bind it to class context inside `constructor`?
3. In yout third snippet's second line your declare `this.navItem` as a class property, but in line 4 you pass it as a prop. Why so? Did you declare `navItem` in the parent component and pass it as a prop?

Comment: Check out my update

Comment: Of course, there is a better way to manage this task. How you declare your `moveBall` method? And (more importantly, according to your uodate) - does `.navigation_item` node belongs to the same component(or it's children) as `moveBall`?

Comment: I'll update my question with the full snippet. the navigation__item class does belong to the same component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last update all you need is just move first call to this.moveBall to react lifecycle hook componentDidMount. This ensures that DOM will have `.navigation_item` nodes in it. So, remove lines

```
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const activeState = document.querySelector('.navigation__item .active')
        this.moveBall(activeState)
    });
```

from `render` method and add `componentDidMount` method to your class, like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const activeState =  document.querySelector('.navigation__item .active');
  this.moveBall(activeState);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Do I need to import anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your moveBall function is being called with `undefined` as the argument at some stage. The `event.target ?` check then crashes with the error you gave.

The `onMouseOver` is likely always fine, as React supplies that.

Instead, I imagine it's the manual call you gave at the end. Is there a time when your `this.props.navItem` doesn't have a value?

Worth logging out that property right before calling the function to be sure it's always as you expect.

Comment: Yea it does output as I expect. It doesn't have a target property though which is why im getting the error but I thought the ternary operator would go `oh no target lets just make it event instead`

Comment: oh your right. it isn't defined yet. Its like the dom hasn't been created yet

Comment: Thanks for your help michael